# postgresql slow performance but NOT SLOW inside query

Tags: performance, hibernate, postgresql

Our Company working on a web App in java that combining with spring framework. For database side of application we use hibernate and our database is postgresql. I am on of developers and recently I have this strange problem only on my computer. retrieving data from database in our web application is so slow. there is not any common problem about slow query because when I run a query inside the database directly by postgresql query tools , there is not any slow retrieving problem.even I used one of my coworker's system as a database server.so the web application deployed inside my computer and the database server was inside another computer and strangely I had no speed problem. The data retrieved from database through web application was very fast!!! What's going wrong? is there a problem about my hard?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: Without much inside information, but with some experience with the same software stack, I would start finger pointing at Hibernate.... Could you start some profiling? And check the fetching strategy, this can make a HUGE difference!